# Cloning protected git repository in Xcode 4

Tags: git, xcode4

I'm trying to clone an existing git repository by giving Xcode the url (repository is in codebasehq). The url looks like:

```
git@codebasehq.com:company/project/repository.git
```

But Xcode can't clone because:

```
The operation could not be performed because access to the repository "repository" was denied.
```

Should I add something to that url in order to identify?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set up your SSH key correctly, is it in your .ssh folder, and is it named id_rsa (the default) did you type in your password when it requested it (or is it available in keychain at least?). In my case with Github I just had to try twice and it worked without issues, so maybe try again... or try cloning locally into a directory first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had limited success with using Xcode 4 and private remote repositories.  When it has worked, it has always been when I accessed the repository via https.  You might try that.  I suspect Xcode 4 has authentication issues.

Of course, you should verify that your can access the repository via SSH first to make sure your key is being exchanged correctly.